# How can I get an Epson TX560WD scanner working?

Tags: 11.10, 64-bit, scanning, epson

I have a Epson TX560WD, the printer works perfectly on Ubuntu 11.10, but the scanner don't.

I installed XSane and xsane-extras, but the scanner it's not recognized either way. When I open XSane the following message shows up: "no device available".

According to Sane Project the Epson TX560WD is tagged as "Complete", so it should work (I guess so).

http://www.sane-project.org/lists/sane-backends-external.html

Also my Ubuntu 11.10 is 64 bits.

What I should do, to make the scanner work?

- Tried installing iscan but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download from [Here](http://www.avasys.jp/lx-bin2/linux_e/spc/DL2.do)

and download this files :

```
iscan-network-nt_1.1.0-2_amd64.deb
iscan-data_1.11.0-1_all.deb
iscan_2.27.1-4_amd64.deb
```

then

```
sudo dpkg -i packagename (with each packed)
```

You can see also the [PDF](http://linux.avasys.jp/drivers/iscan/doc/userg_revO_e.pdf)....

Comment: It was a little trickier but now works perfectly! I have to install first iscan-data_1.11.0-1_all.deb, after that I have to install libltdl3 dependency, then iscan_2.27.1-4_amd64.deb and iscan-network-nt_1.1.0-2_amd64.deb (in this order to work). After all the three are installed is necessary reboot the system. Now it's working like a charm. Thanks a lot hhlp!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try installing iscan?  That's what I had to do to get my Epson NX420 Printer/Scanner scanning properly.

http://www.avasys.jp/lx-bin2/linux_e/spc/DL1.do

Select your model number and then on the next page you'll be presented with all the download options.

Comment: I followed your instructions, downloaded and installed the appropriated driver to my model, but it doesn't make any difference.

I'm still getting "no device available" from XSane.