# Lexmark Intuition S505 Scanner not detected by Simple Scan

Tags: scanning, scanner, lexmark

First post here. I've migrated from Windows to Ubuntu 11.10 - yeah! I've managed to get everything working except my scanner. It's a **Lexmark Intuition S505** and not listed at all here http://www.sane-project.org/sane-mfgs.html#Z-LEXMARK.

1. Could someone help me with the troubleshooting steps. I am a complete Ubuntu newbie
2. As it's not listed I assume I should write to SANE directly, but I want to make sure I've completed  basic troubleshooting first. e.g. it seems you can sudo an call xsane from the terminal, so more details would be appreciated
3. Should I raise a request with Lexmark?
4. Are there any driver files similar to those listed on [How can I get an Epson TX560WD scanner working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/71137/how-can-i-get-an-epson-tx560wd-scanner-working) that would help me?

I have Simply Scan but when I try to scan it says No scanner detected. I use he same Lexmark Intuition device as a printer which works like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

Lexmark supports this printer with linux drivers. Use this link to install the latest version.

[Support Page](http://support.lexmark.com/index?locale=en&page=product&productCode=LEXMARK_INTUITION_S505&segment=SUPPORT&userlocale=EN_US&frompage=null#1)

Then sane should work.
You may also need to add yourself to the `lp` user-group.

I would also check for a file in the `/.sane/xsane` folder for a file name like `Lexmark:S505.drc`, this would be the scanner configuration for SANE.